# Ubuntu Server 18.04 does not show Intel SW RAID(RAID 0 or RAID 1) device in Partition Manger

Tags: 18.04, raid

My Intel system is configured with RAID 0(2 disks) or RAID 1(2 disks) in BIOS.
And I use the image from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/
to perform installation.

During "Detect disks" stage, it asked if I want to "Active MDADM constainers (Intel/DDF RAID), I answered "yes". Then it asked my if I want to "Activate Serial ATA RAID device", I answered "yes" also.

However, in "Partition disks" stage, it does not show me any disk information.

With Ubuntu Server 16.04, the installation works without issue on this system.

Answer (score 2):

When asked:
Active MDADM containers (Intel/DDF RAID), choose "yes"

It will then ask:
Activate Serial ATA RAID device, at this point wait and switch to a shell by pressing "alt+f2"

Press Enter to activate the console

Then run the command "mdadm --stop /dev/md127"

Next activate the intel dmraid by running the command "dmraid -ay"

Press "alt+f1" to go back to the installer.

Now you can answer the
Activate Serial ATA RAID device with "No".

It should now pick up your Intel RAID.

Comment: I literally ran into this issue installing 18.04 LTS to a dual node supermicro server.  This was like the 2nd answer on Google.  Thank you!

Comment: I stopped all devices which I finded in "cat /proc/mdstat" and then "dmraid -ay".

Answer (score 1):

You should not use dmraid for Intel Raid arrays, as it has moved to mdadm for a long time now. dmraid is limited in many ways for Intel Raid arrays. For example - limited disk size / raid array size.

Are you booting in UEFI? If not, you probably should. We regularly test Intel Raid array installation with d-i based server installer and mdadm and it does work with 18.04.1 LTS (which ships updated mdadm with many Intel Raid array fixes).

Did you setup Volume0 or similar in the pre-os/uefi screens? And if after that raid arrays were not detected, please extract /var/log/syslog from the installation environment and open a bug report on launchpad against mdadm or debian-installer package.