# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Intel RAID (RST) can't detect the RAID

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, raid, intel, mdadm

I've created RAID10 in BIOS (Intel RST). In 16.04 everything was OK. And in 18.04 I can't see my raid at all. I choose:

1. Active MDADM containers (Intel/DDF RAID) => "yes"
2. Activate Serial ATA RAID device => "yes" or "no"

Either yes or no in the 2nd point - I don't see my RAID at the next step.

How can I properly install 18.04 Server on the Intel RST (RAID10)? And why in 16.04 everything is OK and in 18.04 there are problems, what changed?

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034836/ubuntu-server-18-04-does-not-show-intel-sw-raidraid-0-or-raid-1-device-in-part helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't support it. I am heaving the same problem. One solution is to set all the disks in non-RAID mode at Bios and furing the installation you create the RAID than install it.

Also, be aware that for you to be able to create the RAID during the installation, you can't use the live version, you will need the Bionic Beaver installer (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/)

Please let us know if you succeed.

Cheers,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is deadly old, but for some others that are coming here with the same problem, in my case the solution was to enter in BIOS and activate mode RAID on, changing it from the previous AHCI mode.
With AHCI mode it was working under Ubuntu 16.04 with mdadm 3.3, however in 18.04 mdadm is version 4.1 and according to man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mdadm.8.html:

```
IMSM_NO_PLATFORM
              A  key  value of IMSM metadata is that it allows interoperability with boot ROMs on
              Intel platforms, and with other major operating systems.  Consequently, mdadm  will
              only allow an IMSM array to be created or modified if detects that it is running on
              an Intel platform which supports IMSM, and supports the particular configuration of
              IMSM that is being requested (some functionality requires newer OROM support).

              These  checks  can  be suppressed by setting IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 in the environment.
              This can be useful for testing or for disaster recovery.  You should be aware  that
              interoperability may be compromised by setting this value.
```

Apparently RAID ON is needed to the new version of mdadm to detect a platform that supports IMSM.